# Speech framework iOS 10: Recognition of letters, not words

Tags: ios, xcode, speech, sfspeechrecognizer

The new [Speech framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech) is great. However, I'm looking for a way to recognize spoken letters, not just words. The Apple TV does this to enter  [usernames and passwords.](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT200107)

iOS Dictation recognizes individual letters if you preface your speech with the keyword "upper case". This works in Speech as well, but I need an 'always-on' solution.

Any suggestions on how to do this using Speech?

Comment: 1. Prefacing with "upper case". Considering that's not documented, I'd say that's progress. 2. I was hoping 'contextual strings' would allow for some kind of custom dictionary, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you already found a Solution for your problem ?

Comment: It seems that this is a problem only for some Languages, for german it works even with letters. And I dont have to preface my speech with the keyword "upper case"

Comment: In my app, German letter dictation works much better when using the preamble "Großbuchstaben" (i.e. capital letters). I also set the locale manually to narrow down the results. In my opinion, the documentation is really not helping a lot if you try using SiriKit to its full power.